# Yii Minscript Error with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, yii, minify, yii-extensions

I tried minifying the Jquery Mobile javascript file Using [YII minscript](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/minscript/) extension which wraps [Minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/). But i keep getting a javascript file that seems to be missing a few codes and throws errors. I did a bit of digging and discovered that the code section below of Jquery Mobileseem to be the problem. I guess because of the double slash (//).

The code section not minifying properly:

```
isPath:function(e){return/\//.test(e)}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved the problem:

```
isPath:function(e){return/(\/)/.test(e)}
```

I just wrapped the content of the double slash in parentheses. Could this be buggy?